# Calling asmx web service from angualrjs throws 500 on IIS only, not VS2013 (IIS Express)

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, asmx

I have a piece of Angularjs code in the UI to my ASP.net website.  In this Angular code I call an ASMX Web Service to get some data.  This works find when I run the application from Visual Studio 2013 (which uses the IIS Express server).  But when I deploy to the IIS server (either on my development machine or a Server 2008 production system) when the code tries to access the service it throws a 500.0 error.

The Angular call is :

```
        getItemsUser: function (UserTypeID) {
            var params = { "UserTypeID": UserTypeID };
            return $http({
                url: "MainServices.asmx/GetItemsForUser" 
                method: "POST",
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8' },
                data: JSON.stringify( params ),
                dataType: 'json'
            })
```

this returns a Promise that immediately errors with the 500.0.

The function code in the ASMX code-behind is

```
<System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService()> _
<WebService(Namespace:="http://tempuri.org/")> _
<WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo:=WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)> _
<Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.DesignerGenerated()> _
Public Class MainDisplayServices
  <System.Web.Services.WebMethod(Description:="GetItems", EnableSession:=False)>
   Public Function GetItemsForUser(UserTypeID As Integer) As List(Of Item_Row)

      Return Controller.GetItemsForUser(UserTypeID)

   End Function
```

In the IIS log the entry returned is:

```
2015-01-26 03:50:26 ::1 POST /site/MainServices.asmx/GetItemsForUser - 80 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.3;+WOW64;+Trident/7.0;+rv:11.0)+like+Gecko http://localhost/site/Main.aspx 500 0 0 250
```

Any ideas on how to troubleshoot this issue?

FWIW, I have tried adding the attributes to change the POST to GET and there is not change in behavior regardless of the verb.

Jerry

Comment: What's the exception? Can you check the event viewer

Comment: Can you add a breakpoint to the web service code and step into it?

Comment: Found the error.  The problem was the "EnableSession:=False".  The Controller was contained in an Application level container.  Since the Application is a special case of Session session creation must be enabled.  So setting EnableSession:= True fixed the issue.   Apparently IIS Express must ignore this setting or handles the session differently.